# Ошибка SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault)

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

Есть функция:

```
void to_lower(char* s)
{
    for (int i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++)
        if (s[i] >= 65 && s[i] < 90)
        {
            s[i] += 32;
        }

}
```

После строки `s[i] += 32`, выдает ошибку Segmentation fault.

Comment: Возможно, вы передаете в функцию некорректную строку.

Comment: char *s = const_cast<char *>("Hello, World");
    to_lower(s);

Comment: @CheshireCat серьезно? Это же строковой литерал! Он только реад онли.

Comment: Тогда как мне создать C-строку, не только для чтения?

Comment: Создайте массив (инициализируемый литералом) или просто `std::string`.

Comment: @CheshireCat вы знаете как снять константу, но не знаете как создать строку? Поддержу VTT, но если вам нужна конкретно "с-строка", то создайте массив char-ов.

Comment: @Cheshire Cat: То есть тот факт, что вам пришлось использовать `const_cast` вас не навел ни на какие сомнения?

Answer (score 1):

```
char s[] = "Hello, World"; 
to_lower(s);
```